# xpath to validate text before and after <br/>

Tags: xpath

following is my html table structure and i want to validate the complete text inside td using x-path `<tr><td>Sagar Nair<br/><b>Owner</b> - Verified</td></tr>`

can anyone help for this.

Comment: And what is this "validation"? What does it have to do with xpath? (Apart from retrieving the content of the TD.)

Comment: want to validate input value "Sagar nair Owner - Verified"

Comment: 'validate' usually means that some data must matche certain conditions or constraints. What are the conditions or constraints the value "Sagar nair Owner - Verified" should match?

Comment: I was looking someting like "//tr[td[contains(text(),'sagar nair') and ....

Answer (score 0):

When the `tr` element in your example is the current element, then the XPath expression `string(.)` will have as its value the string you say you would like to validate.  For the actual validation of the string you are going to need some language other than XPath; since you don't mention a programming language, however, I assume that once you get the string you know what to do with it.